# XSLT: split elements with proper structure

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to split the following element structure based on the break element as mentioned below. Tell me some suggestions to convert using XSLT.

**INPUT:**

```
<root>
      <div>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <break/>    
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <break/>    
                <li>Item 5</li>
                <li>Item 6</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
      </div> 
</root>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<root>
      <div>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 5</li>
                <li>Item 6</li>
            </ul>
        </p> 
      <div>
</root>
```

Comment: Please see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples and the example "Identifying a Group by its Final Element" using `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with`. Adapt that to your needs, if you are stuck, post your effort.

Comment: Thanks I will try.